# Как починить Missing styles?

Tags: android

Вот у меня вот такая ошибка, не знаю как починить. Уже и тему менял и кастомную подключал, все равно висит вот такая ошибка, что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот appTheme**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это ошибка предпросмоторщика студии. Самое верное решение сей проблемы - не пользоваться им. Пользуйтесь реальным девайсом и/или эмулятором.

Comment: Так обычно этой проблемы нет... Именно в этом проекте я куда то не туда нажал или что то где то пропустил и вот такое получилось

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Это норма, на работу программы не повлияет, если сильно бесит, то можно сменить версию API на панельке сверху со скриншота

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, по идее как примерно выглядеть должна написанная разметка вы должны в голове представлять, а реально смотреть на реальном девайсе. Предпросмоторщик всегда будет с глюками, т.к. полезен только для простейших задач и для новичков и в гугле его до ума доводить не будут, ибо это нецелесообоазно. Засим пользоваться им не стоит вовсе.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK А где там на скриншоте смена версии API? Прошелся по всем иконкам и не нашел...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Я представляю как должна выглядеть разметка, но мне как новичку очень удобно пользоваться предпросмоторщиком, так как он сразу показывает что и как, где добавить отступ, а где я забыл выставить посередине. Это удобнее чем каждый раз перезагружать проект в телефон

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Я не знаю какую версию Android Stduio вы используете, но у меня версия 1.4 и сменить версию API я могу на панельке, где у вас на скриншоте изображено "AppTheme", там же у меня есть смена версии API

Comment: @BORSHEVIK я добавил описание к вопросу со скриншотом appTheme про которую вы говорите. Вы сказали, что у меня на панельке вы видете эту кнопку на которую нужно нажать, чтоб поменять версию API вот я прицепил все скриншоты скажите конкретно на какую кнопку нажать?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Я не сказал, что я её вижу, я сказал, что на панельке, которая изображена на скриншоте эта кнопка должна быть, у меня нарисован зелёный Android и рядом цифры (Это версия API)